# table nesting multicolumn into multirow

Tags: tables

I am trying to nest multicolumn in a multirow but my code doesn't properly close the table in the first row. How to fix this?

[image]

[image]`

Comment: Please never post screenshots of your code. Instead post the code as text, so that is easy to copy and manipulate it. Anyways, you need to replace the column definition in the second `\multicolumn` macro so that it becomes `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{b-c}`.

Comment: Actually, all you need is use {c|} instad of {c} in the rightmost \multicolumn.  (\multicolumn eats vertical lines.)

Answer (score 2):

`tabularray` is much simpler.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{title}
\centering
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec      = {Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]},
hline{1,3,Z} = {},
vline{1,Z}   = {},
cell{1}{2,4} = {c=2}{},
cell{1}{1}   = {r=2}{},
}
a & b-c &    & b-c &    \\
  & b2  & c2 & d2  & e2 \\
r & 1   & 2  & 3   & 4  \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First off, it's not clear why you choose an very small column width for all five columns. Second, since line-breaking within cells doesn't seem to be needed (or even permitted), I wouldn't use a column type that permits line breaking and use the `w` column type instead. Third, the missing vertical line arises because you use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{...}` instead of `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{...}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{array} % for 'm' and 'w' column types
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}      % optional
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}} % optional
\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{4} % just for this example

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Dummy table}
\begin{tabular}{| *{5}{wc{3mm}} |} % choose suitable column types/widths
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{a} 
   & \multicolumn{2}{c }{b-c} 
   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{b-c} \\ % <- note the "|" symbol
   & b2 & c2 & d2 & e2 \\ \hline
r  & 1  & 2  & 3  & 4  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```